# How to output list of unique entries in a tab-delimited file

Tags: linux

I have a file

```
1 ABC 123 345 Apples

1 ABC 345 345 Apples

1 ABC 123 345 Apples_Fuji

1 ABC 123 345 ApplesApplesApples

1 ABC 123 345 Pears

1 ABC 123 345 Banana
...
```

I wish to get an output file

```
Apples 2

Apples_Fuji 1

ApplesApplesApples 1

Pears 1

Banana 1
...
```

I'm not sure whether grepping them one at a time would work (-o would be inaccurate anyway, -c is strangely giving me a value of 1 everytime).

Answer (score 1):

Solution with cut,sort,uniq

```
cat test | cut -f5,5 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: I think the cut command could do with a delimiter to make it a little more flexible

Comment: Yes. It would do. But for the given input above the delimiter is tab and which is the default delimiter for cut. Hence I did not mention.

Comment: Very fair point. I clicked the up arrow in approval of your answer. I am not very impressed with the other much more long winded answers to this question because they seem overly complicated for a simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `awk`:

```
$ awk '{arr[$NF]++}END{for(i in arr) print i,arr[i]}' file
ApplesApplesApples 1
Apples 2
Banana 1
Apples_Fuji 1
Pears 1
```

Here's another way, using `grep` and `uniq`:

```
$ grep -oE '[^ ]+$' file | sort | uniq -c
      2 Apples
      1 Apples_Fuji
      1 ApplesApplesApples
      1 Pears
      1 Banana
```

Comment: Awesome. I was pondering along the lines of "awk < file '{print $N}' | sort | uniq" and adding "|wc -l " didn't give me what your answer did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution using awk/sort/uniq could be:

```
cat file|awk '{print $5}'|sort|uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
perl -lane '$h{$F[4]}++ unless(/^\s*$/);END{print "$_ $h{$_}" for(keys %h)}' your_file
```

Tested Below:

```
> cat temp
1 ABC 123 345 Apples

1 ABC 345 345 Apples

1 ABC 123 345 Apples_Fuji

1 ABC 123 345 ApplesApplesApples

1 ABC 123 345 Pears

1 ABC 123 345 Banana
> perl -lane '$h{$F[4]}++ unless(/^\s*$/);END{print "$_ $h{$_}" for(keys %h)}' temp
Pears 1
ApplesApplesApples 1
Banana 1
Apples 2
Apples_Fuji 1
>
```